# Create a ZipFile and add to it a txt file with a string from memory

Tags: c#, compression, sharpziplib

I am using SharpZipLib but I could not find any example on how to crate a new ZipFile and add to it a file containing an string from the memory (and not from an existing file). Any suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen updating a zip file in memory here: https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Updating#Updating_a_zip_file_in_memory_1

Answer (score 2):

Check their GitHub page, it has plenty of samples -> https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples